# Login and Register With Xamarin App in ASP Web API

Tags: asp.net, authentication, xamarin.forms, oauth, access-token

Hello everyone I'm new to mobile development (Xamarin), I develop a **Xamarin-Form** application with an authentication (Login & password) via a **WebAPI server** (**Identity**) that works well and authentication by social networks like **Google**, **Facebook** , **Twitter** ... thanks to **Xamarin Auth** I was able to recover the **Token** and other user information (Email, Name, Id ...) of these different **Service Provider**.

My problem comes from the fact that I do not know how to make the best use of this token that is offered to me with my WebService for complete authentication of my users.

- I wanted to save user data from Google (name, email ...) as a new user using my normal registration methods but I find it strange because I should still ask for a password for the new account that I must create in the background.
- By loading into the WebAPI project I am falling on an AddExternalLogin method but I did not find how it could solve my problem.

If anyone knows how I could use the information from the authentication by social networks (Facebook, Google ...) with identity or advice ... I'm interested.

but how strange is the good?

Comment: Read online oauth 2.0 tutorial you will get the idea of how different endpoints and tokens work.

Comment: **Thank you** ... I went through the documentation of Oauth and followed some additional Tutorial but I found nothing that tells me how to use the user information (from Google for example) with Identity (WebAPI)